# Image Comparison using await/async JS

Tags: javascript, image-processing, promise, async-await

I am completely new to JS and need to do image comparison with it. I want to use async/await JS functions so page loading is now slow, but I have absolutely no idea where to start. Would anyone mind explaining how async/await works and potentially show me a quick dummy example using two "image" parameters?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Assuming you want your JavaScript to run in the browser, you'll need to learn how to use `npm` and Babel to use `async`/`await`. If that's not the case, you may want to say so in the question.

Comment: I do want my JavaScript to run in the browser. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @robinsax async/await is supported is all current major browsers except IE (which it not receiving any new versions).

Comment: Async/await is just a fancy way of writing Promises. Maybe start here: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely look at that.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I wouldn't encourage the use of a language feature with 85% browser support.